# Cmake cannot not find include/lib directories generated by Conan

Tags: python, cmake, conan, conan-2

I am trying to define both a recipe file and a `test_package` for NATS 3rd party library.
Here is the folder structure which I have:

```
nats
|--conanfile.py
|--test_package
   |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--conanfile.py
   |--test.cpp
```

After running command

```shell
conan create . "nats/3.6.1@myname/test" -pr <some_profile_file>
```

both `nats` library and its dependency - `openssl` are being successfully built, because after running `conan search nats` and `conan search openss` I can see the following packages in localhost:

```
Existing package recipes:
nats/3.6.1@myname/test
openssl/3.1.1_0@jenkins/stable
```

`conanfile.py` recipe file for `nats` has the following structure:

```
import os
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.scm import Git
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeDeps, CMakeToolchain, cmake_layout

required_conan_version = ">=1.59.0"

class NatsConan(ConanFile):
    name = "nats"
    description = "NATS is a simple, secure and high-performance messaging system."
    version = "3.6.1"
    license = "Apache-2.0"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    
    options = {
        "shared"                 : [True, False],
        "nats_tls"               : [True, False],
        "nats_build_streaming"   : [True, False],

        "windows_sdk"            : "ANY",
        "full_compiler_version"  : "ANY"
    }

    default_options = {
        "shared"                 : False,
        "nats_tls"               : False,
        "nats_build_streaming"   : False,

        "windows_sdk"            : "10.0",
        "full_compiler_version"  : ""
    }

    short_paths = True

    def config_options(self):
        if self.settings.os != "Windows":
            del self.options.windows_sdk

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        cmake = CMakeDeps(self)
        cmake.generate()
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.variables["NATS_BUILD_STREAMING"] = self.options.nats_build_streaming
        tc.variables["NATS_BUILD_WITH_TLS"] = self.options.nats_tls
        tc.variables["BUILD_SHARED_LIBS"] = self.options.shared
        #tc.variables["NATS_BUILD_OPENSSL_STATIC_LIBS"] = True
        tc.generate()

    def source(self):
        git = Git(self)
        git.clone(url = "https://github.com/nats-io/nats.c.git", target = ".")
        git.checkout("v3.6.1")

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("openssl/3.1.1_0@jenkins/stable")
        if self.options.nats_build_streaming:
            self.requires("protobuf/3.18.0_13@jenkins/stable")

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["nats"]
```

`test_packages`'s `CMakeLists.txt` file see below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(test_application CXX)

find_package(nats CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_application test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_application nats::nats)
```

And the `conanfile.py` file for that:

```
import os

from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, cmake_layout
from conan.tools.build import can_run

class TestApplicationConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires(self.tested_reference_str)

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def test(self):
        if can_run(self):
            cmd = os.path.join(self.cpp.build.bindir, "test_application")
            self.run(cmd, env="conanrun")
```

The problem is that when `conan` command runs `test()` for the `test_package` it just can't find neither include directories (I have `#include <nats/nats.h>` in the `test.cpp` file and called a function from `nats`) nor library directories.
I have tried to add this line in the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```cmake
include_directories(${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

and resolved only compile error. But unfortunately I can't resolve the linkage error, because, I guess, I need to somehow specify in the `CMakeLists.txt` file where the generated `lib` folder is located.

Also, I don't think that including `${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH}` explicitly is the right solution (it seems to me like a workaround).
IMO, there should be a generated file which should be included and nothing else, e.g., I have added this generated file

```cmake
include(C:/.conan/d6e9bb/1/lib/cmake/cnats/cnats-config.cmake)
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt`, but this didn't help either :(.

I don't understand what I am missing or maybe I misunderstood something related to Conan and CMake interaction. My `Conan` version is **1.59.0**.

Comment: I will have a look to your report, just a note first: ``windows_sdk`` and ``full_compiler_version`` as options doesn't sound great. It seems the first sounds better as a Windows subsettings in ``settings.yml``, and the second could be maybe the ``msvc`` ``compiler.update`` subsetting?

Comment: When installing files directly from `cmake.install()` is really important to pay attention what and where are installed. I built your files (thanks for sharing), the headers looks good, but you are also installing cmake and .pc file from nats. You should remove them in prior of using those generated by `CMakeDeps`. You can add after `cmake.install()`:  `rmdir(self, os.path.join(self.package_folder, "lib", "cmake"))` and `rmdir(self, os.path.join(self.package_folder, "lib", "pkgconfig"))`.

Comment: @drodri Honestly, I don't have enough knowledge to explain why both `windows_sdk` and `full_compiler_version` are used. I copied those options from other 3rd party libraries' recipe files which my company has in its repository (we can 3rd party libraries internally)

Comment: Seems to be working fine here, so far headers where located perfectly. What CMake version are you using? 3.15 is the minimum required for CMakeDeps/CMakeToolchain integration

Comment: @drodri my cmake version is 3.25.0

Comment: It seems there could be some issues also with the nats build scripts, because even if you are defining it to be static library by default, I see it is packaging a DLL. Maybe it is hardcoded in the nat build scripts, this is something to check

Comment: @uilianries Is it required to remove `cmake` and `pkgconfig` or it is just having everything as clean as possible?

Comment: This is an inconvenient place for support-like. I'd recommend moving this to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues github issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254388/discussion-between-david-hovsepyan-and-drodri).